# Curve with a hook?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]
I linked the curve point with a empty object. curve moves with this object"hook" but when I rotate or change size the curve not changing. How to fix this?

Comment: It does work for me... could you add some details about what is hooked inside the curve?

Comment: This what I do. Add curve -> path, click on edit mode and choose any point from the curve. Ctrl+H choose first option.

Comment: You should upload your file using this link: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I solved. I choose "Path" not "Bezire". Thank you Lemon.